# How can I interpolate missed values of time series in pythonic way?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following time series and I want to interpolate the missing values:

```
                          value
DateTime                      
2016-10-01 00:00:00  19.123
2016-10-01 01:00:00  19.567
2016-10-01 02:00:00  19.753208
2016-10-01 03:00:00  19.753208
2016-10-01 04:00:00  17.624113
2016-10-01 05:00:00  18.301900
2016-10-01 06:00:00  19.371016
2016-10-01 07:00:00  20.354912
2016-10-01 08:00:00  NaN
2016-10-01 09:00:00  NaN
2016-10-01 10:00:00  NaN
2016-10-01 11:00:00  NaN
2016-10-01 12:00:00  NaN
2016-10-01 13:00:00  NaN
2016-10-01 14:00:00  NaN
2016-10-01 15:00:00  19.753208
2016-10-01 16:00:00  19.753208
2016-10-01 17:00:00  17.624113
2016-10-01 18:00:00  18.301900
2016-10-01 19:00:00  19.371016
2016-10-01 20:00:00  NaN
2016-10-01 21:00:00  Nan
2016-10-01 22:00:00  Nan
2016-10-01 23:00:00  Nan
```

I used the following code but not right:

```
df.set_index('DateTime').resample('H').interpolate()
```

Comment: maybe `df.interpolate()` ?

Comment: Your dataframe seems to already have `DateTime` as index?